# How to display keyboard shortcut next to menu item in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm working with `MenuItem` in XAML, using `InputGestureText` I have added Keyboard shortcuts to menu items. What I'm confused about is how to display keyboard shortcut in the actual menu next to each item that has keyboard shortcut.

I don't want to add text to `Header` but rather display value of `InputGestureText` therefore it can be changed without having to modify header.

I'm using [WPF Localization Extension](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/)

Code for `Menu`

```
<Menu Grid.Row="0" Height="30" >
        <MenuItem Header="{lex:Loc Project75:lang:mnuFileMenu}">
            <MenuItem Header="{lex:Loc Project75:lang:mnuFileMenuNew}">
                <MenuItem Header="{lex:Loc Project75:lang:mnuFileMenuNew}" Command="{Binding Path=NewCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+N"/>
                <MenuItem Header="{lex:Loc Project75:lang:mnuFileMenuNewEmailTemplate}" Command="{Binding Path=NewEmailTemplateCommand}" />
                <MenuItem Header="{lex:Loc Project75:lang:mnuFileMenuNewContact}" Command="{Binding Path=NewContactCommand}" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="{lex:Loc Project75:lang:mnuFileMenuImport}" Command="{Binding Path=ImportCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+I"/>
            <MenuItem Header="{lex:Loc Project75:lang:mnuFileMenuExport}" Command="{Binding Path=ExportCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+E"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="{lex:Loc Project75:lang:mnuFileMenuSave}" Command="{Binding Path=SaveDocumentCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+S"/>
            <MenuItem Header="{lex:Loc Project75:lang:mnuFileMenuSaveAll}" Command="{Binding Path=SaveAllDocumentsCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+Shift+S" ToolTip="Closes all open Windows"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="{lex:Loc Project75:lang:mnuFileMenuClose}" Command="{Binding Path=CloseDocumentCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+F4"/>
            <MenuItem Header="{lex:Loc Project75:lang:mnuFileMenuCloseAll}" Command="{Binding Path=CloseAllDocumentsCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+Shift+F4"/>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="{lex:Loc Project75:lang:mnuFileMenuExit}" Command="{Binding Path=ExitCommand}" InputGestureText="Alt+F4"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="{lex:Loc Project75:lang:mnuHelpMenu}">
            <MenuItem Header="{lex:Loc Project75:lang:mnuHelpMenuAbout}" Command="{Binding Path=AboutCommand}"/>
        </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: I am assuming you also want to account for modifiers too (Ctrl, Shift, Alt)?

Comment: When I do this <MenuItem Header="Open" InputGestureText="Ctrl+I" /> it displays the shortcut right next to the header. What is the problem? Same applies if I assign a Command to the menu item that has an InputGesture defined. Did you possibly define a custom template for MenuItem that overrides the default style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="controlTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Header}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=InputGestureText}" Margin="5,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Foo">
            <MenuItem Header="Bar" Command="Copy" Template="{StaticResource controlTemplate}"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

I'm using the copy command as example but you can use any other command. Header can be localized as you are doing.

Comment: You almost had it just had to make small changed. `Path` in second `TextBlock` just had to be changed to `Path=InputGestureText` and it works like magic. Thanks so much.

Comment: You could update your answer in response to Vladimir's question.